# C++ boost signals and slots with different parameters?

Tags: c++, boost, signals, slots

Can a C++ signal be linked to slots with different parameter lists?

i.e. one slot takes 1 parameter, the other one takes 2, etc...

And you then call that signal with 1 or 2 parameters and it calls the corresponding slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the arity of a `signal` instance is defined by its type. If you examine the definition of the [`boost::signals2` template class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/signal.html) (or the deprecated [`boost::signals`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/signals/reference.html#header.boost.signal_hpp)):

```
template<typename Signature, 
         typename Combiner = boost::signals2::optional_last_value<R>, 
         typename Group = int, typename GroupCompare = std::less<Group>, 
         typename SlotFunction = boost::function<Signature>, 
         typename ExtendedSlotFunction = boost::function<R (const connection &, T1, T2, ..., TN)>, 
         typename Mutex = boost::signals2::mutex> 
class signal : public boost::signals2::signal_base {
```

The calling signature of the signal and its slots are fixed in the template parameters.

A workaround would be to define an `Event` argument type that can contain multiple kinds of data, e.g. defined by subclasses.